# How to handle key press to avoid deletion of input text field data

Tags: angular

i'm trying to handle key press to avoid deletion of input text field data when delete button on keyboard is pressed.

This is my input field html code:

```
<input type="time" class="custome-text-input" [(ngModel)]="d.hoursofoperationfrom"  formControlName="hoursofoperationfrom" [required]="days[i].checked" [readonly]="!days[i].checked">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `keydown` event.

When delete key is pressed, [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) should be called on the event.

Template:

```
<input type="time" class="custome-text-input" [(ngModel)]="d"  (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)">
```

component.ts

```
public onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode === 46) {   // 46 - Delete key
      event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5mpfcu)